# CORS error while accessing through path params

Tags: aws-lambda, cors, aws-api-gateway

I have an AWS API Gateway with Lambda proxy integrations for GET methods on

- /resource/{id}
- /resource

when i send a request from localhost to these endpoints, i get CORS error on preflight requests for /resource/{id} and for /resource it works without any issue.

In both case i am sending a get request using axios in react.

What is going wrong here. Any pointers to this will be helpfull.